# Yield complete block in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handle, yield

I wondered how I can yield the complete block which I pass to my component.
I already found this https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/components/block-params/
but I don't understand why there is

```
//my-component.hbs
{{#if hasBlock}}
  {{yield post.title}}
  {{yield post.body}}
  {{yield post.author}} ...
```

Why I have to name what I want to yield? That makes no sense because I want to yield (display) the whole block which I pass to the component, regardless what I do there.

So I tried just to use yield only:

```
//my-component.hbs
{{#if hasBlock}}
  {{yield}} ...
```

and use the component this way:

```
//myroute.hbs
{{#my-component car=model}}
  {{car.name}} - {{car.color}}
{{/my-component}}
```

This doesn't work, but I expected that 'car.name - car.color' will be rendered in the {{yield}} of the component...

Can someone explain me this, please?

Comment: Have you tried ember-twiddle.com  that's awesome for learning ember and reproducing specific issues and asking for clarification. there is more chance for you to get what exactly you need.

Comment: Thanks, I will use it next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit confusing, I admit.  What is happening is the component is yielding (returning) values that you can use in your block.  Try something like this:

```
{{#my-component car=model as |car|}}
    {{car.name}} - {{car.color}}
{{/my-component}}
```

Then in your component:

```
{{#if hasBlock}}
    {{yield car}}
{{else}}
    default no-block template goes here...
{{/if}}
```

Here's a working twiddle: https://ember-twiddle.com/9a0efb92ebea6f206236a32e3c3e6053?openFiles=templates.index.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs

Comment: thanks for answer. So is this a kind of security, meaning I can only use values and models which are defined in the yield?

Comment: Sorry, just saw this question.  Not really a security concern.  The design concept behind components is that they do not have any context- they are unaware of the current model.  To ensure re-usability, all data must be injected into a component from the route.